# Add a listner to input element in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have the below posted `input` element. I want to know how can i add a listner to the `input`element in such a way that, every time the user change the input values that listener gets invoked and displays the current values
chosen

**HTML template**

```
<div id="idDoseLabel1" class="date">
  <p>{{ "SITE.INSECTICIDES.DOSE_LABEL" | translate }}:</p>
</div>
<input id="idDoseValue1"
    [disabled] = "false"
    required
    placeholder=""
    maxlength="7" 
    clrInput
    type="number"
    name="doseValue"
    [(ngModel)]=iPesticidesDosesPasser.dose
    #name1="ngModel"/>
```

Comment: Could you please format the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onChange event on your input element, so as soon as the value changes. You can do something like this:

```
<input id="idDoseValue1" [disabled]="false" required placeholder="" maxlength="7" clrInput type="number" name="doseValue" [(ngModel)]=iPesticidesDosesPasser.dose #name1="ngModel" (change)="someFunction($event)"/>
```

and in `someFunction()` function you can get the value from variable `iPesticidesDosesPasser.dose`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change  event for input, like this:

```
<input id="idDoseValue1"
  [disabled] = "false"
  required
  (change) = "test()"
  placeholder=""
  maxlength="7" 
  clrInput
  type="number"
  name="doseValue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormControl` to achieve the same.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="idDoseLabel1" class="date">
    <p>{{ "SITE.INSECTICIDES.DOSE_LABEL" | translate }}:</p>
</div>
<input [disabled] = "false"
    [formControl]="doseControl"
    required
    placeholder=""
    maxlength="7" 
    clrInput
    type="number"
    name="doseValue"/>
```

**TS code:**

```
doseControl = new FormControl('');

ngOnInit() {
    this.doseControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
};

//to retreive value
this.doseControl.value;

//to set value
this.doseControl.setValue('new value');
```

Comment: I totally agree with that